# Is there a pattern for configure function override pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

A interface defines a series functions func1 to func20. There are many derived classes which implements only parts of these 20 func. The implementation of func has its own pattern, for example: f1's implementation has 2 kinds, f2's implementation has 3 kinds. The derived class will implements about 3 to 5 number func defined in interface and all those implementations is chosen in defined kinds. Most of func in a derived class is empty means do nothing when outer model call it by refer a interface.
Is there a pattern to make fixed implementation to object and use them to config derived class? For example: Derived class D1 needs to implements f2 & f10, f2 use the first kind implementation which chosen from all 3 kinds. f10 use the second kind implementation which chosen from all 2 kinds.

My solution right now is simple: only derive from interface and override the functions it needs to, but the problem is: the increase of func implementation is much slower than derived class, because derived class construct by combination of different func. I have to hard copy code of func implementation code into derived class, that is not good. It is hard to maintain.

I want to make derived class configurable by primitive func codes, is it possible?

=====================================================================

I am clarify my problem and decorator indeed could solve this.

```
interface A {
    f1();
    f2();
    ...
    f20();
}
```

f1-20 implementation is not arbitrary, they has fixed pattern. f1() has 3 kinds implementation, say, {1a},{1b},{1c}. f2() has 2 kinds: {2a},{2b}. Derived class which implements A only needs to override small number functions about 3-5. As you can see, the possible derived class definition(random chose some fn() to override and chose a kind of implementation from each fn()) is a combination, and number is huge. The consequence is fixed fn's implementation will be copied every where.

Decorator solve this in manner of put every fn's implementation such as {1a} into a decorator of interface A. So if we want a derived class only override f1 & f2 by {1a}{2b}, compose {1a}{2b} decorators to a object. The key is define a abstract class decorator base:

```
abstract class DecoratorBase : A {
    A a;
    DecoratorBase(A a){this.a=a;}
    f1(){a.f1();}
    f2(){a.f2();};
    ...
    f20(){a.f20();};
}
```

And define some default process into base A (this can be omit if there is no default common process)

```
class BaseA {
    f1(){} // no default code, do nothing
    f5(){/*default code*/}
}
```

First kind implementation of f1():

```
class F1A : DecoratorBase  {
    F1A(A a){super(a);}
    f1(){super.f1();/*1a*/}
}
```

Second kind implementation of f2():

```
class F2B : DecoratorBase  {
    F2B(A a){super(a);}
    f2(){super.f2();/*2b*/}
}
```

Finally, combine them:

```
new F1A(new F2B(BaseA()));
```

Comment: So: Is your problem actually that virtual methods slow down your computation? And which language is it you are implementing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, Decorator pattern seems appropriate?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Possibly combined with Factory and/or Builder pattern.

Comment: Well, I just suggested the Decorator as one way of concatenating a group of functions. If no communication is needed, Collection is probably a better bet. Common interface for the partial functions. Use Factory to configure the 2-3 configurations that you actually use.